# Real Conditional Clause + Present Unreal Main Clause

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, modal-verbs, semi-modals, deontic-vs-epistemic

Is it grammatical to say these four sentences?

1. If I **have studied** it for four years, I should be good at it.
2. If I **had studied** it for four years, I should be good at it.
3. If I **have been studying** it for for four years, I should be good at it.
4. If I **studied** it for four years, I should be good at it.

Comment: (2) and (4) need _would_ instead of _should_. Everything else is OK.

Comment: I don't think *I’m supposed to be good at it if I’ve studied it for four years* sounds so bad.

Comment: **Since or as** I have studied or studied it for four years, I should be good at it. [not including British usage of should in 1)]